Troubles at installing TeXLive 2024
From one year to another I don't really remember what I do.
I just know there's 8.0GB under /usr/local/texlive/2023, so that's the installation I'm currently using. I now want to install TeXLive 2024.
The quick install guide seem to have become better!
However, I still can't get it all :D
Right now I'm in /tmp/install-tl-20241106, and I've tried running perl ./install-tl --no-interaction. The result is this:

Loading https://mirror.apps.cam.ac.uk/pub/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb

   
./install-tl: TLPDB::from_file could not get texlive.tlpdb from: https://mirror.apps.cam.ac.uk/pub/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
Maybe the repository setting should be changed.
More info: https://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html

What's happening?

Side question (which I don't know if its related), the guide says (step 5) to run


perl ./install-tl --no-interaction # as root or with writable destination


which to me looks a bit of a contraddiction: if I'm not specifying the location on the command line, then that location is either the current dir, which doesn't seem to make sense, because I'm ultimately under /tmp, if I followed step 1


cd /tmp # working directory of your choice


or that location is some default location dicated by the install-tl script, so how can I know if it's writable?

personally, I never use --no-interaction and I never install as root. however non-root install requires you to set things up so you don't need root. (a dedicated use texlive owns my tl installation.) if you are tempted by --no-interaction, that is probably not for you, so just use sudo or su -c or su or whatever method your distro prefers.

and yes, the default pick has become increasingly flaky the last couple of years. it didn't work for me out-of-the-box either. so use the link it provides, pick a different mirror and switch it. I suspect you are in the UK or nearby. it works OK on github, so it seems to be something with one of the mirrors around here.

The default destination is /usr/local/texlive. Use sudo chown -R ${UID}:${GID} /usr/local/texlive and the default destination is writable by current user.

@cfr, I am indeed in the UK.

@PaulGaborit, my Bash doesn't have $GID. Is that supposed to be the same as id -g, like I read here?

Maybe see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187379/ re. installing not-as-root. I would not recommend installing as yourself either. (Disclaimer: my answer.)

@cfr, I've left a couple of comments there to ask some clarification :/

@Enlico Yes, $GID is supposed to be the same as id -g (for the current user).
